# Как в laravel сделать автоматическое присвоение id в связанных таблицах?

Tags: laravel

Есть несколько связанных таблиц через hasOne(). Модель user.php связана с Profile.php. Модель Profile.php связана с Country.php и City.php

В Profile.php есть поле user_id. В Country.php есть поле profile_id. И в City.php есть поле profile_id.

Собственно сам вопрос.

Как правильно сделать при регистрации пользователя, автоматически заполнять поля в связанных таблицах. Именно user_id, profile_id

Пока что делаю так.

В RegistersUser.php

```
 public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $this->guard()->login($user);

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $profile = new Profile;
    $profile->user_id = $user_id; 
    $profile->save();

    $country = new Country;        
    $country->profile_id = $user_id;        
    $country->save();

    $city = new City;        
    $city->profile_id = $user_id;        
    $city->save();      


    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

По мне так это выглядит очень неправильно. Наверняка есть способ легче. Помогите справиться с задачей.

Comment: Выглядит немного странно. То есть, при создании пользователя Вы создаете новую запись в city и country, которая имеет только одно ненулевое значение - profile_id ?

Comment: Да все правильно. Нужно при регистрации пользователя автоматически создать записи в связанных таблицах profile country и city. В таблицах countrys и citys по умолчанию поля будут созданы в виде Страна не указана и Город не указан. Потом пользователь если пожелает сможет изменить на свои значения. Просто сейчас выглядит странно что нужно создавать три отдельных объекта и записывать их отдельно. Много обращений к базе. Скорее всего есть способ грамотнее.

Comment: А Вам не кажется, что логичнее было бы у пользователя добавить поля city_id и country_id ? Ведь логично, что у пользователя может быть один город и одна страна.
ну и реализовывать логику: если выбрал из имеющихся уже стран - то id из country, если новую добавил, то добавить запись о стране в таблицу country и users.country_id добавить её id

Comment: В принципе можно и так но хотел сделать все связи через таблицу Profiles. Так как в последствии будет много других связанных таблиц с профилем. Потом нужно будет организовать поиск по критериям. И я подумал что через таблицу профиля будет удобнее делать поиск.

Comment: А в чем сложность будет поиска по критериям?
Например, пользователь выбирает страну, выбирает город. Хватаете id выбранных элементов и делаете выборку, типа `SELECT * FROM users WHERE country_id = выбранное значение and city_id = выбранное значение.`
Естественно, используя Query Builder от laravel.

Comment: Ну и исходя из всего вышесказанного, складывается впечатление, что требуемый функционал - немного бредовая вещь и вряд ли для нее разработчики предусмотрели решение попроще))

Comment: $user->city->attach($city), $user->profile->attach($profile)

Comment: @Orange_shadow, так ему вряд ли подойдет, это же тоже ручками делать нужно))

Comment: @Vasily Koshelev  он спросил есть ли другие способы :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = Auth::user(); // Текущий пользователь

/* Например если он связан с моделью App\Post - при таком создании 
связь сама проставит id в нужные поля согласно правильной настройки 
связей в моделях (проверено в типах связей 'один ко многим' и 'один к 
одному' )*/

$user->posts()->create([
   'title' => 'test',
   'content' => 'test desc'
]); // у posts в поле user_id запишется id текущего пользователя
```

Comment: но перед этим нужно описать связи в моделях